# Save Data with HTML

Tags: javascript

This is my layout:

[image: Watch this first]

My table was **created row by row** using:

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    data += '<tr align="center">';
    data += '<td>' + value.dayNumber + '<input type="hidden" name="dayNumber" value="' + value.dayNumber + '">' + '</td>';
    data += '<td>' + value.dayName + '</td>';
    //get amount of types of Clients
    for (var i = 0; i < clientTypes.length; i++) {
        data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center amountOfClients" type="number" value="0" name="amountOfClients-' + clientTypes[i] + '" id="amountOfClients-' + clientTypes[i] + '"  data-error="Please, insert a value"  required>' + '</td>'
        data +=  '<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
    }
    data += '</tr>';
});
$('.dayTableBody').append(data);
```

**So it obviously saves the data row by row, mixing everything**. So I tried to correct this using a name dynamic.

```
name="amountOfClients-' + clientTypes[i]
```

created a lot of complexity later on when I'm trying to save data using Ajax.

```
//This code doesn't work and it's not clean.
  var data;
    for (var i = 0; i < clientTypes.length; i++) {
        data = $('#amountOfClients-'+clientTypes[i]);
        for (var j=0;j<maxDays;j++) {
        }
    }
```

**So my question is:** *Is there a simpler way to save data by column so I can have the data like: all the data from column Individual first and then column Corporation.*

Comment: Why don't you use `$.each` to iterate the `clientTypes`, but use it for `data`?

Comment: can you explain? I'm sorry but I dont understand

Comment: Use `$.each()` for `for (var i = 0; i < clientTypes.length; i++) {` also.

Comment: and delete `+ clientTypes[i]` from name? Please, can you write an answer with code?

Comment: Working right now so maybe a bit later.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: so, what you are trying to do is retrieve the data from the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. Before I give you the code, let me explain the basic idea.

The gist of it is that we have an in-memory store for the data, keep it in sync with the actual state of the table, and then extract the data from this store instead of from the DOM. There's a bit more code in the end, but a bit more elegant than dancing around the DOM tree.

We first create an in-memory storage for the data. This could just be a copy of your `data` object that comes from the backend, or whatever. The important thing is that we keep it accessible to the rest of the code so it can be manipulated.

The data to be manipulated (individual and company values) are stored in the same place as the rest of it. For simplicity, I've stored them as individual keys, but you can do that any other way.

I wrote a function that will manipulate this data store:

```
  function update(idx, field, val) {
    data[idx][field] = val;
  }
```

This function needs an array index, a field name (`individual` or `company`), and the new value. This is also what I'll need to store in the table markup later on.

While still working with the data, I define a function that will extract the useful parts of the data store. This is the main part of it:

```
data.reduce(function (acc, rec) {
  acc.individuals.push(rec.individual)
  acc.companies.push(rec.company)
  return acc
}, {
  individuals: [],
  companies: [],
})
```

The `reduce()` function accepts a callback and an accumulator. The callback function takes the same accumulator, and an item from an array, and returns an updated accumulator. In our case, we collect the `individual` and `company` values form our array items. Reduce walks down the updating the accumulator with the data from each of the array items, and you end up with something like:

```
{
  individuals: [0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0],
  companies: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12],
}
```

Now the rest of the code is mostly just rendering the table, and hooking up event handlers, so I won't go into too much detail. You should be able to find everything you need in the documentation.

Since I don't know what you are going to do with the data and when, I've just wired the whole thing to dump the JSON version of the data into a textarea.

Anyway, here's the code. Hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/foxbunny/twj30auf/